Ville-like inequality for double-indexed martingales
Given a non-negative (super)-martingale $M_t$ (with respect to a filtration $(F_t)$), such that $M_0\equiv 1$, Ville's inequality states that
$$\mathbb P(\exists t>0: M_t\geq 1/\delta)\leq \delta\,,$$ where $\delta\in (0,1)$ is fixed.
Now consider a family of sigma-algebras $(F_{t,n})$, such that $F_{t,n}\subseteq F_{t,n+1}$ and $F_{t,n}\subseteq F_{t+1,n}$. Is there some similar result for a non-negative process $M_{t,n}$, adapted to $(F_{t,n})$, such that $M_{0,0}\equiv 1$ and
$$\mathbb{E}[M_{t, n}|F_{s, m}]\leq M_{\min(t, s), \min(n,m)}\,?$$
I mean, is there a result like
$$\mathbb P(\exists n>0, \exists t>0: M_{t,n}\geq 1/\delta)\leq \delta\,?$$
Or is some weaker version of this at least possible?
